# Dynamic navigation bar with jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to create a "changing" navigation bar.
The nav bar should change with a click on one of the nav elements.

the code looks like this :

```
<ul>
  <li> Type
    <ul>
      <li> <a href=""> one </a></li>
      <li> <a href=""> two </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li> Gender </li> // Lets say that this is replaceable
```

if I click on "one" it's "Gender".
and when I click on "two" it's suppose to change to "blabla".

I wanted to ask what is the best way to replace the nav menu with jQuery, 
I tried replacing the HTML with .html() func but I don't know where to save my replaced code.

Meaning, I wanted to know what is the best way to keep all the code on the DOM and each time change the nav bar when clicked.

Thanks, 
robi

Comment: Whatever the answer will be, please don't use empty `href`. It causes different behavior depending on the browser. At least, use `#` or... don't use `<a>`

Answer (score 0):

This solution needs jQuery 1.4.3 or higher.

**Your HTML**

```
<ul>
  <li> Type
    <ul id="mymenu">
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Gender"> one </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" data-text="Blabla"> two </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="target"> Gender </li> 
</ul>
```

**Your JS**

```
$('#mymenu a').click(function(e) { 
         e.preventDefault(); 
         $('#target').text($(this).data('text')); 
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a class="Gender" inside your  and when the user clicks change the visibility status of your li where you have used an id="Gender"

Clearly you start with all lis not visible

```
<ul>
  <li> Type
    <ul id="mymenu">
      <li><a href="#" class="Gender"> one </a></li>
      <li><a href="#" class="Age"> two </a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li id="Gender" class="dynamic"> Gender </li>
  <li id="Age" class="dynamic"> Gender </li>  
</ul>
```

your JS

```
 $('#mymenu a').click(function(e) { 
         e.preventDefault(); 
         ... [Change visibility accordingly]
     });
```